# Ansible two default files per distro

Tags: ansible

I'm writing an Ansible role that is supposed to run on Debian and RedHat.

In my module, the default values for Red Hat and Debian are different, so I thought I could just create Debian.yml and RedHat.yml in the default folder, but this did not work out of the box.

Where can I set the appropriate values so this works just like for vars?

I tried it in the same way with:

```
- name: Include distribution specific variables
  include_vars: "{{ ansible_os_family }}.yml"
  tags: module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Ansible doesn't let you include defaults.

What you can do tho, is include vars like this:

```
- name: "Include distribution specific vars"
  include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found: "{{ ansible_facts['distribution'] }}.yml"
```

then override included vars when needed, with:

```
- name: "Override vars"
  set_fact:
    var: "{{ override_var }}"
  when: override_var is defined
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `main.yml` files are loaded automatically, files `Debian.yml` and `RedHat.yml` in `defaults` directory aren't loaded automatically. You could load them with task `"Include distribution specific variable"` that you wrote, this task must be the first task in `main.yml` file in your role as below

```
- name: Include distribution specific variables
  include_vars: "defaults/{{ ansible_os_family }}.yml"
  tags: module
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly and follow your suggestion, I get the error message: ERROR! failed to combine variables, expected dicts but got a 'dict' and a 'AnsibleSequence':

Comment: The task "Include distribution specific variable" must be in your main.yml but in tasks directory not in defaults directory. Just files in tasks directory can have tasks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Variables in the var directory get loaded, but not in the defaults directory.

Comment: My mistake, it's necessary add the path defaults like this include_vars: "defaults/{{ ansible_os_family }}.yml". Try in this way. I've modified my first answer.